# Web Application Engineer VS Web Application Developer

Tags: web-applications

I am confused in between these two key words. 
not found clear and sufficient words in internet searches.
some where written both are same. only difference in key words.

Comment: I doubt there's any "official" distinction.  Most job titles/descriptions are created independently by the person/company writing them, with very little prescriptive industry standard.  Is there a particular reason you're looking for a distinction between the two?

Comment: nop no any reason. and @David  seriously i am not asking any official distinction. it was just in my mind. after lot of searches i have posted it here

Comment: Aside from being generally off-topic and not constructive for Stack Overflow (so the question will likely be closed), it really is a purely subjective distinction.  There's no difference between the two titles per se, though any given company or hiring manager may internally use them to distinguish between different expectations and responsibilities.

Comment: An Engineer has been anointed the Engineer title by educational body or government.  Everyone else is not an Engineer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An engineer is usually the person that designs the whole system, from the ground up, from concept to structure.

The developer is the one who codes that concept, into something concrete.

But the reality is, that most people wear both hats.

Hell developers can even cross over into designer territory.

Its not unusual to be all.....where I work, I am developer/engineer of both front-end and back-end.

The bigger the company, the more the roles will split.

Smaller companies prefer a person who can wear many hats.

Comment: `"An engineer is usually the person that designs the whole system, from the ground up"` - This is very subjective and can drastically change from one place to another.  A lot of companies will refer to this person as an "architect" and the developers are "software engineers."

Comment: Thats very true....I guess the point Im trying to make is the lines are very blurry...lol

Answer (score 0):

It is just words.

I have worked in *many* projects and teams and find that in the software engineering/development profession there are very few formal titles, if any.